# How to i go live from localhost with python files??? it is not working just like other normal html php files

Tags: python, django, web, shared-hosting

I tried uploading my website created with python in localhost with django framework, but it is not working but showing the directories.
Usually when a website is developed in PHP, when we upload with the index files the hosting auto fetches which is not  happening here.
the site made with python has also the index.html file but i have it inside sub folders.
So the summarized question is how to move my python website from local server to live?

Answer (score 2):

A website needs to be located on a server. There are a lot of server providers available on Internet from which you can choose. I have tried pythonanywhere which is also free for small applications and uses. So it might be helpful for your first time deploying the django application.

The following links would be helpful:

- https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/
- https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/